# using beatifulsoup4 to scrape a specific part of html code

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am wanting to make a variable equal the 1.65 towards the end of the html code. Currently if i was to run my code it will print "price-text". Any help to be able to swap it to print "1.65" would be great.

```
<div class="priceText_f71sibe"><span class="size14_f7opyze medium_f1wf24vo priceTextSize_frw9zm9" data-automation-id="price-text">1.65</span></div>
```

[html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQFWD.png)

```
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
price_texts = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"priceText_f71sibe"})
price_text = price_texts[0]
a =price_text.span["data-automation-id"]
print (a)
```

Comment: `a = price_text.span.text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most popular is property `.text`

```
price_text.span.text
```

But there are other properties and methods

```
price_text.span.text
price_text.span.string
price_text.span.getText()
price_text.span.get_text()
```

Documentation for method [get_text()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text)

Full working code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<div class="priceText_f71sibe"><span class="size14_f7opyze medium_f1wf24vo priceTextSize_frw9zm9" data-automation-id="price-text">1.65</span></div>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

price_texts = soup.findAll("div",{"class":"priceText_f71sibe"})
price_text = price_texts[0]
a = price_text.span["data-automation-id"]

print(price_text.span.text)
print(price_text.span.string)
print(price_text.span.getText())
print(price_text.span.get_text())
```

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you!